# getMonth function cannot be found

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to get a sheet to populate data in a new tab, I need three columns type, service and date/month.  However, the getMonth statement keeps throwing an error and I'm unsure why?

```
var service = inputSheet.getRange('O' + lastRow).getValue();
var date = inputSheet.getRange('L' + lastRow).getValue();
var month = date.getMonth();
```

I expected this to return the date held in variable date as the month it was entered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to explicitly create a JavaScript / Google Apps Script Date object using the value returned by getValue():

```
var date = new Date(inputSheet.getRange('L' + lastRow).getValue());
var month = date.getMonth();
```

Note: getMonth() returns a value 0 - 11 not 1 - 12.